# Infinite Loop without crash

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, internet-explorer, redirect, infinite-loop

I have a VB Project that is a web browser. 
If WebBrowser1's url is google.com at any time I would like to change its url to bing.com (These urls are for example only!)

```
Do
        If WebBrowser1.Url = ("http://www.google.com") Then
            WebBrowser1.Navigate(New Uri("http://www.bing.com"))
        End If
    Loop
```

Above is a code that I have tested but every time I use it it will crash and cause the program to not respond.

Does anybody know a better way of doing this? At the moment I am a novice programmer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an event-driven approach.

Instead of infinitely looping to check for `WebBrowser1.Url` changes, simply handle a `WebBrowser1.Url`-changed event in an appropriate delegate - something *like** this:

```
Private Sub webBrowser1_Navigating( _
    ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs) _
    Handles webBrowser1.Navigating

    If e.Url.OriginalString = "http://www.google.com/" Then
        WebBrowser1.Stop() ' Thanks, @Steve.
        WebBrowser1.Url = New Uri("http://www.bing.com")
    End If
End Sub
```

The conditional check will then only occur when necessary, avoiding the program paralysis.

Check out the [`System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.Navigating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event's reference; and [help with events and delegates in VB.NET](http://www.bing.com/search?q=vb.net%20events) is widely available too.

*I say *like* because I am not nailing down every little detail on my machine, just providing general direction.  Also, checking for an exact URL match may not be as helpful as something a bit more flexible - e.g. that does not assume an HTTP URL scheme and accounts for the possibility of a HTTPS URL scheme etc.

Comment: Add a call to Stop() in the Navigating event.